# Вывод из базы данных в заданном порядке

Tags: php, sql

Мне нужно выводить статьи из базы данных в заданном порядке.

Например, есть в базе данных столбец `datatype` со значениями `0`,`1`,`2`,`3`. Нужно организовать переменную `$order` так, чтобы выводились данные по порядку `3`,`0`,`1`,`2` или по другому заданному.

Comment: база данных какая у вас? если MSSQL SErver , то можно написать CASE прямо в ORDER BY

Comment: mySQL я работаю на локальной машине через phpmyadmin

Comment: Спасибо всем большое за оперативный ответ. Буду пробовать.

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте в выводе ещё одну колонку, в которую поместите значение для сортировки, и делайте ORDER BY по этой колонке. Т.е. примерно так:

```sql
SELECT *, 
    CASE 
        WHEN datatype=3 THEN 1
        WHEN datatype=0 THEN 2
        WHEN datatype=1 THEN 3
        WHEN datatype=2 THEN 4
    END as orderIdx
FROM table1
ORDER BY orderIdx
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(id,2,4,1,5,3);
```

Хочу сделать правку, оказалось что запрос работает  некорректно, если не указан IN(...) для чисел которые указаны в порядке сортировки.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE status IN(0, 3) ORDER BY FIELD(status, 0, 3)
```

С таких запросом все работает. Но, сомневаюсь что такой вариант вам подойдет.

Comment: Это не запрос работает некорректно, а вы просто не дочитали документацию. Функция FIELD возвращает индекс (начиная с 1) в списке если значение поля из списка, и 0 если нет. Таким образом, запрос должен выглядеть так: `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(id,3,5,1,4,2) desc;`. Т.е. в обратном порядке список и общая сортировка тоже.

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @t table (i int);
declare @order int = 3;

insert into @t (i)
values (0), (1), (2), (3)


select * from @t
order by case 
            when @order = i then -1
            else i 
         end
```

для MS SQL Server , можете оформить как ХП с параметром.

2. Вариант для php (MySQL):

   ```php
   $order = '3';
   $query = sprintf("select id from mytable order by case when id = %s then -1 else id end", $order);
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   ```

Comment: я не особо в этом всем силен...
Что такое ХП???

Comment: это хранимая процедура (stored procedure).  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: а как-нибудь  php обойтись можно?
без данных процедур

Comment: можно конечно, сформируйте строку SQL с параметром и выполните. вы используете скорее всего mysql_query? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score -2):

Попробуйте

```
ORDER BY 'datatype'='3', 'datatype'='0', 'datatype'='1', 'datatype'='2', 'datatype' DESC
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: На личном опыте.